# Boolean value in nested foreach scope gives unexpected value

Tags: php, arrays, scope

I have an array of arrays. They are all rows of people that subscribed for a seminar. At the end of the table there are some upsell products added. Problem is: sometimes someone orders for 2 people and the upsell products, that belong to a transaction, not to a person are joined behind both persons. So If I sign up 2 people and buy 2 shirts the list states 2 shirts twice.

So I thought: let's loop through it, see if I find some upsells and then remove every second occurence with a simple double `foreach`. But the value of `$first` remains `true` always. While it is `false` if I echo it below the declaration. I echoed the values several times and I added the value in comments the code.

```
foreach($results as $key => $result){
    if(!empty($result["upsell"])){
        $tid = $result["id"];
        $first = true;
        foreach($results as $result2){
            if($result2["id"] == $tid){
                // ALWAYS TRUE
                if(!$first){
                    $results[$key]["upsell"] = "";
                }
                $first = false;
                // FALSE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some weird scope thing going on here? In my opinion it should loop first and be true then loop second and be false.

EDIT, added the `print_r` of results.

```
Array
(
   [28] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1475
        [transaction_id] => SAME
        [club] => xxxxxxxx
        [event] => Voetbalmiddag 
        [category] => Scoutingdagen
        [date_from] => 2017-05-31
        [date_end] => 2017-05-31
        [first_name] => xxxxxx
        [last_name] => xxxxxx
        [birth_date] => xxxxxxx
        [email] => xxxx@hotmail.com
        [address] => xxxxx
        [zipcode] => 8xxxxx
        [city] => xxxxxx
        [phone] => xxxxxx
        [soccer_club] => xxxxxxx
        [soccer_team] => MP JO7-2
        [position] => field
        [printed] => 0
        [print_name] =>  
        [print_number] =>  
        [shirt_size] => 
        [sock_size] => 
        [pants_size] => 
        [referral] => Via de sportvereniging
        [comments] =>  
        [status] => paid
        [upsell] => 2 Shirt
    )

[29] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1476
        [transaction_id] => SAME
        [club] => xxxxxxx
        [event] => Voetbalmiddag
        [category] => Scoutingdagen
        [date_from] => 2017-05-31
        [date_end] => 2017-05-31
        [first_name] => xxxx
        [last_name] => xxxxxxx
        [birth_date] => xxxxxxx
        [email] => xxxxx@hotmail.com
        [address] => Ixxxxx
        [zipcode] => xxxxx
        [city] => xxxxxx
        [phone] => xxxxx
        [soccer_club] => xxxxx
        [soccer_team] => MP JO9-9
        [position] => keeper
        [printed] => 0
        [print_name] =>  
        [print_number] =>  
        [shirt_size] => 
        [sock_size] => 
        [pants_size] => 
        [referral] => Via de sportvereniging
        [comments] =>  
        [status] => paid
        [upsell] => 2 Shirt
    )

[50] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1468
        [transaction_id] => xxxxxxx
        [club] => xxxxxxxxxxx
        [event] => Voetbalmiddag
        [category] => Scoutingdagen
        [date_from] => 2017-05-31
        [date_end] => 2017-05-31
        [first_name] => xxxxx
        [last_name] => xxxxx
        [birth_date] => xxxxx
        [email] => x@gmail.com
        [address] => xxxx 35
        [zipcode] => xxxx
        [city] => xxxxx
        [phone] => xxxxx
        [soccer_club] => xxxx
        [soccer_team] => jo11-5
        [position] => field
        [printed] => 0
        [print_name] =>  
        [print_number] =>  
        [shirt_size] => 
        [sock_size] => 
        [pants_size] => 
        [referral] => Via de flyer
        [comments] =>  
        [status] => open
        [upsell] => 1 Shirt
    )

)
```

Comment: What is the structure of $results

Comment: !$first is true,  $first is false. What's the problem?

Comment: @KrisRoofe I want $first to be false in the second iteration of the second foreach, but somehow it restarts with `$first =  true` every time while it is set to false on the first iteration.

Comment: @RST It's an array with associative arrays.

Comment: That is not really helpful. The issue might be that you are looping over the same array. Your code could be improved if the structure of the array was known

Comment: print_r($results)

Comment: check the demo https://eval.in/795450

Comment: @KrisRoofe I added the results. Your results are even weirder, you lose the upsell for [0] and [3]. Thanks for your help so far though!

Answer (score 1):

```
...
$first = true;
$results1 = $results;  
foreach($results1 as $result2){
...
```

Comment: This didnt help unfortunately!